# Get BluetoothDevice from AltBeacon's Beacon object for GattConnection

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am ranging for beacons using AltBeacon's android-beacon-library and getting back results. To connect to GATT services for this beacon (to configure the beacon), I need the BluetoothDevice of the Beacon. Is it possible to get the BluetoothDevice?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.

Just use:

```
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(beacon.getAddress());
```